# Magento2 - Searching and filtering products in admin panel, horrifically poor performance. Does this not get Indexed?

Tags: magento2, search, elasticsearch, magento2.3.4

In the admin panel product tab, is their anyway to increase the performance of searching and filtering?  I have a huge number of products, and it takes at least `45` seconds minimum to get any response.

Does that even get indexed? I have `ElasticSearch 5` configured, shouldn't that make this at least usable?

Answer (score 1):

No, the backend doesn't get indexed. You can visit below URL to see how to improve your backend speed : [Why Your Magento 2 Admin Panel Is Slow and How to Fix It](https://onilab.com/blog/magento-admin-back-end-slow/)